# Creating JS file on the fly

Tags: javascript, caching

I have a code that generate a big bunch of javascript code and I would like to create a .js file on the fly and include the code in it.

The code would be reconstructed at each cache destruction. The file would be used by all visitors.

Any ideas what I could use to make this possible? Or there's no "drupal way" to do this?

thank's!

Comment: I have a similar question here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66163/use-a-views-result-as-a-javascript-setting if anybody could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this in this way:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_init(){
    drupal_add_js('path/you/want/to/use/to/include/javascript.js');
}

function YOUR_MODULE_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['path/you/want/to/use/to/include/javascript.js'] = array(
        'title' => 'Generated js',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'page callback' => 'your_function_name'
    );
    return $items;
}

function your_function_name() {
    $js = ... your code that composes js here ... ;
    print $js;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: This is good answer, `drupal_add_js` will cache output returned by `your_function_name`, but I think you missed `'access callback' => TRUE,` in `hook_menu`

Comment: Even better would be I think putting js code to template file and loading it with theme() function call. Just not to mess php and js code in one file.

Comment: Great and concise, that's what I was looking for :). Thank's to both of you !

Comment: It is works for me but I'm also getting message in Chrome `"Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html"` How to set up MIME type or solve this warring?