# Use a view's result as a javascript setting

Tags: views, javascript

I am trying to integrate the Supersized javascript library (http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) into my site.

It requires an array of image urls when initialized.

I would like to use a view to populate this array so that my content editors can easily update the site with new background images.

Does anyone know how to do this with Drupal 7?

I have seen the http://drupal.org/project/supersized module, but as far as I know it doesn't work with views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Supersized wants a slides array with the information about each image.  You could build the slides array dynamically from the view.

Two fields in the view:
(1) The image,
(2) The image thumbnail

The slides array wants these properties: image, title, thumb and url.

You could derive the image src, the title and the url from the image field (make sure it links to something).
You could derive the thumbnail src from the image thumbnail field.

And here is some code that with modification should work just fine (taken from [Supersized demo page](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html)):

```
jQuery(function($){

  var slidesFromView = [];

  $(".view-supersized .views-row").each(function(){
    var rowImage = $(this).find(".views-field-image img").attr('src');
    var rowTitle = $(this).find(".views-field-image img").attr('title');
    var rowThumb = $(this).find(".views-field-image-thumb img").attr('src');
    var rowUrl = $(this).find(".views-field-image a").attr('href');
    slidesFromView.push({image: rowImage, title: rowTitle, thumb: rowThumb, url: rowUrl});
  });

  $(".view-supersized").hide();

  $.supersized({

    // Functionality
    slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
    autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
    start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
    stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
    random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
    slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
    transition              :   6,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
    transition_speed        :   1000,       // Speed of transition
    new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
    pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
    keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
    performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
    image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

    // Size & Position                         
    min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
    min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
    vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
    horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
    fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
    fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
    fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

    // Components                           
    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
    thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
    thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
    slides                  :   slidesFromView,

    // Theme Options               
    progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         
    mouse_scrub             :   0

  });
});
```

Comment: Great answer!  I think that concept will work.  Me runs off to try it...